# Include Column_Id as atttribute in FOR XML PATH

Tags: sql-server, xml, identity-column

Let see this sql query

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customer 
WHERE Id = 60 
FOR XML PATH ('Customer'), ELEMENTS XSINIL, TYPE
```

It returns XML like this

```
<Customer xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <Id>60</Id>
      <BranchId>5</BranchId>
      <DocKind>3</DocKind>
      <Document>SomeDoc</Document>
....
```

How can I add `Column_id` as Xml attributes to each node?

This is the query returning `Column_Id`'s of table `Customer`:

```
SELECT COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME),
    COLUMN_NAME, 'ColumnID') AS COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Customer'
```

I want result like this:

```
<Customer xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Id ColumnId=1>60</Id>
  <BranchId ColumnId=2>5</BranchId>
  <DocKind ColumnId=3>3</DocKind>
  <Document ColumnId=4>SomeDoc</Document>
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution:

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(MAX) = 
'select ' + STUFF(( SELECT  ',' + CAST(COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(TABLE_SCHEMA + 
                            '.' + TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'ColumnID') AS VARCHAR(10)) + 
                            ' as ''' + COLUMN_NAME + '/@ColumnID'', [' + COLUMN_NAME + ']'
                    FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                    WHERE   TABLE_NAME = 'Customer'
                    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') + 
' from Customer FOR XML PATH(''Customer''),ELEMENTS XSINIL, TYPE'   
EXEC (@s)
```

Comment: where is "one row" s values?

Comment: please read again , i need result like this   <Customer xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Id ColumnId=1>60</Id>
  <BranchId ColumnId=2>5</BranchId>
  <DocKind ColumnId=3>3</DocKind>
  <Document ColumnId=4>SomeDoc</Document>    values are one row's values

Comment: @ArmenKhachatryan, see edits, unfortunately you have to use dynamic query so can not help with second question.

Comment: @ArmenKhachatryan, yes you can use `insert into some table exec(@s)`

Comment: @ArmenKhachatryan, didn't get. May be you will give me your technical doc and I will make job for you? I can't answer your million question. Ask another questions. This question is answered already

Comment: Write me your email and i will do it :))  , OK thank you for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

If your in SQL Server, I think you can you a correlated subquery for each field such as:

```
(select top(1) COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME),
COLUMN_NAME, 'ColumnID') AS COLUMN_ID
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Customer' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'BranchId') as 'BranchID/@Column_ID'
```

This is a quick application of the information given in [TSQL FOR XML PATH Attribute On , Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492938/tsql-for-xml-path-attribute-on-type).

With some sample data it'd be easier to see if it works...

```
CREATE TABLE Customer (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), BranchID INT) 
GO
INSERT INTO Customer SELECT ID FROM (VALUES (1),(2)) x(id)
GO

SELECT (SELECT TOP(1) COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME),COLUMN_NAME, 'ColumnID') 
          FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
         WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Customer' 
           AND COLUMN_NAME = 'ID') AS 'ID/@Column_ID'
     ,ID
     ,(SELECT TOP(1) COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'ColumnID') 
         FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Customer' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'BranchId') AS 'BranchID/@Column_ID'
     ,BranchID
 FROM Customer 
WHERE Id = 1 FOR XML PATH ('Customer'), ELEMENTS XSINIL, TYPE
```

And that gets me:

```
<Customer xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ID Column_ID="1">1</ID>
  <BranchID Column_ID="2">1</BranchID>
</Customer>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but result of teq quey you wrote, is : <Customer xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Id Column_ID="1" />
  <ID>60</ID>
  <BranchId Column_ID="2" />
  <BranchID>0</BranchID>
</Customer>

Comment: I want some generic method, so I do not want to specify all te column names , maybe they will be more

Comment: 1. What *exact* rdbms are you using including version?
2. You should specify the columns names in you SQL, in general. However if you can build this sort of thing up in dynamic SQL if you want a generic method for it.