# How to get a XML structure from SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, xml, vb.net, stored-procedures

I am working on a vb.net application, the management wants me to change the applications data source from SQL Server to XML.

I have a class called WebData.vb in the old application I need to somehow find a way to replace the stored procedures in it and make it read xml. So I was thinking of getting the xml structure from the returning result set of the stored procedure. I looked online and they said that for normal select statement you can do something like this:

```
FOR xml path ('Get_Order'),ROOT ('Get_Orders')
```

I am looking for something like

```
EXEC dbo.spMML_GET_ORDERS_FOR_EXPORT
FOR xml path ('Get_Order'),ROOT ('Get_Orders')
```

so now that I have the structure I can pass that data to a datatable and then return that datatable to the method.

Also if there is an alternative way in creating a XML stored procedure please let me know thanks coders.

Comment: If your `dbo.spMML_GET_ORDER_FOR_EXPORT` is just **reading** data, it would be much easier to use a *table value function* instead of this  (best done as *inline TVF*) In this case it is as easy as `SELECT * FROM dbo.YourFunction FOR XML PATH('Get_Order'),ROOT('Get_Orders')`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can't modify the stored proc (due to other dependencies or some other reason) to have the `SELECT` within the proc have the `FOR XML` syntax, you can use `INSERT`/`EXEC` to insert the results of the stored proc into a temp table or table variable, then apply your `FOR XML` onto a query of those results.

Something like this should work:

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE (...) -- Define table to match results of stored proc
INSERT @Data
    EXEC dbo.spMML_GET_ORDERS_FOR_EXPORT
SELECT * FROM @Data FOR xml path ('Get_Order'),ROOT ('Get_Orders')
```

Comment: Additionally, you can set the relations in the XML by Aliases COLUMN AS 'Hillary', and embed a further relation by adding '/' like 'Hillary/Count', as well as embed attributes inside the nodes (add '@' to the Column Name).
Just remember that attribute-centric columns must NOT come after a non-attribute-centric sibling.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few methods, one adding namespaces using `WITH XMLNAMESPACES(<STRING> AS <NAMESPACE string>)`. `XMLNAMESPACES` can embed appropriate `XML` markers to your tables for use with other applications (which hopefully is a factor here), making documentation a little easier.

Depending on your application use, you can use `FOR XML {RAW, PATH, AUTO, or EXPLICIT}` in your query, as well as `XQUERY` methods...but for your needs, stick to the simpler method like `XML PATH` or `XML AUTO`.

`XML PATH` is very flexible, however you lose the straightforward identification of the column datatypes.

**XMLNAMESPACE**

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('dbo.MyTableName' AS SQL)
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Name ASC) AS 'Management_ID'
     , Name AS [Name]
     , Began AS [Team/@Began]
     , Ended AS [Team/@Ended]
     , Team AS [Team]
     , [Role]
FROM dbo.SSIS_Owners
FOR XML PATH, ELEMENTS, ROOT('SQL')
```

**XML AUTO**

Because you might want to return to the database, I suggest using `XML AUTO` with `XMLSCHEMA`, where the `sql datatypes` are kept in the `XML`.

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Name ASC) AS 'Management_ID'
     , Name AS [Name]
     , Began AS [Team/@Began]
     , Ended AS [Team/@Ended]
     , Team AS [Team]
     , [Role]
FROM dbo.SSIS_Owners
FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS, XMLSCHEMA('SSIS_Owners')
```

Downside is `XMLNAMESPACES` is not an option, but you can get around this through solutions like `XML SCHEMA COLLECTIONS` or in the query itself as I showed.

You can also just use `XML PATH` directly without the namespace, but again, that depends on your application use as you are transforming everything to `XML` files.
Also note how I defined the embedded attributes. A learning point here, but think about the query in the same order that the `XML` would appear. That is why I defined the variable attributes first before I then stated what the text for that node was.

Lastly, I think you'll find **Paparazzi** has a question on this topic that covers quite. [TSQL FOR XML PATH Attribute On , Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492938/tsql-for-xml-path-attribute-on-type)